# Adding to the value in a Hashtable [Java]

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm new to java and I was just reading about Hashtables and was wondering how you can manipulate them.

For example if I had a table

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> goalScorers = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
```

and I filled it with names as the key and the integer value at 0

```
goalScorers.put("Ronaldo", 0);
goalScorers.put("Messi", 0);
```

is there a way I could make a method such as

```
public void addGoals(String, int)
```

that could add the int value to the corresponding player that is put in as a string. So if Ronaldo scores two I could add 2 to whatever value is currently assigned to that key (so 0+2 and then next time 2+whatever int value)?

EDIT: Thanks guys, quite obvious now I've seen how (it's 12:30am so thats my excuse)

Comment: Yes, for which you need to pass the reference for your Hashtable to the addGoals function... or make your goalScorers as global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Assuming your Hashtable is global:

public void addGoals(String name, int goals)
{
     goalScorers.put(name, goalScorers.get(name) + goals);  
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get the current score with the method [HashTable.get(Object key)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#get-java.lang.Object-). Note that this will return null if the player is not yet in the table.

For example:

```
public void addGoals(String player, int add )
    Integer currentScore = goalScorers.get( player );
    int newScore = (null == currentScore)
         ? add
         : currentScore + add;
    goalScorers.put( player, newScore );
}
```

By the way, the old class `HashTable` is synchronized. If you don't need this, consider using `HashMap` instead.

Comment: Good that you check for null, and that you make it (somewhat) clear that internally the Map is using an Integer.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, you can do

```
goalScorers.merge("Ronaldo", 2, Integer::sum);
```

That will put the value `2` if there was not already an entry for `"Ronaldo"`, or add `2` to the existing entry if there was one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the confusion is here, but here a possible way to do what you''re asking utilizing `HashTable#get`:

```
public void addGoals(String player, int score) {
  goalScorers.put(player, goalScorers.get(player) + score);
}
```